# User id not displaying in login system

Tags: php

I have been following a dated youtube tutorial and trying to build a login system but I am stuck at some point

Here I want to echo the user id based on the user that logged in but somehow it's not working here is my code for

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require "core.inc.php";
    require "connect.inc.php";
    include "loginform.inc.php";
?>
```

**loginform.inc.php**

```
<?php
    //ini_set('display_errors','1');
    //error_reporting(E_ALL);
    global $conn;
    if(isset($_POST["username"])&& isset($_POST["password"])){
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $password_hash = md5($password);
        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
            $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` ='$username' AND `password` ='$password_hash'";
            if($query_run = mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
                $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
                if($query_num_rows==0){
                    echo "invalid username/password combination";
                }else if($query_num_rows==1){

                    echo $user_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo "you must fill in the username and password properly";
        }
    }

?>
<form action ="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
    Username:<input type="text" name="username"> Password:<input type="password" name="password">

    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

**and connect.inc.php**

```
<?php
    //$conn_error = "could not connect";
    $mysql_host= "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_pass ="";
    $mysql_db ="a_database";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$mysql_db);

     /*if(!mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass) && !mysqli_select_db($mysql_db)){
        die($conn_error);
     }
     */
     if(!$conn){
         die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());

     }

?>
```

the problem is in my `login.inc.php`

on this line

```
echo $user_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
```

but not sure how to fix that

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns an array, you want `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run); $user_id = $row['id'];`

Comment: Putting user input into SQL is not secure. Parameterize, also don't use md5 anymore. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: thanks  user3783243  i would look into  that